# How to design a scalable ETL running on Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-step-functions

I am building an ETL to import data from various Postgres databases into S3 into Redshift. I want my ETL to have the following constraints and goals: 
1. each database involved has one query against it at a time. 
2. minimum time to completion.
3. easy for developer to add new dataset to the ETL.
4. scalable to more database and more datasets.

### A design that fails due to timeout

I had it all planned out with Lambda functions in the following way:

lambda_1: triggered by cron. Triggers several lambda_2's that can run in parallel. Triggers one lambda_2 per source database. Also triggers one lambda_4.

lambda_2: sequentially imports all the datasets from its database into S3.

lambda_3: triggered by a file drop into S3, adds the corresponding dataset name into an SQS queue.

lambda_4: triggered by lambda_1. Has the list of datasets. Pops one message from the SQS queue at a time and imports that dataset from S3 to Redshift. Once it has imported all the datasets on its list, triggers lambda_5.

lambda_5+: (continuation)

I will have problems if there are many datasets in one source database that we want to import, because then the corresponding lambda_2 might timeout before completing the import. 
I will also have problems with lambda_4 for similar reasons, since it will be sequentially importing every dataset from S3 into Redshift.

### A design that makes it difficult to add new datasets

An alternative is to create chained lambdas with *one for each dataset* (perhaps chaining them using Step Functions, for example). I can still decouple the import to S3 from the import to Redshift with the S3 file trigger putting that dataset in an SQS queue.

This solution works but is ugly (imo) and will make it difficult to add a new dataset, since a several new lambdas will have to be created for it.

### Another, better design?

The alternative to all this is to scrap use of Lambda and use ... AWS Fargate? Something else? Looking forward to design suggestions.

Comment: You should run a spark cluster using AWS EMR.

Answer (score 0):

> lambda_2 might timeout before completing the import

Yes, Lambda's 15 minutes timeout is a headache when doing ETL that can take sometime.

If you don't mind using Python I suggest using AWS Glue Python Shell Jobs and potentially AWS Glue Workflow. With Glue Workflows you can have Jobs triggered by other jobs. You will get good visibility and automatic retries.

If that doesn't work out for you then use ECS with Fargate and coordinate with step functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution based on your use case is to use  **Aws glue python shell** jobs, they will act as an extended lambda for you.

You can then orchestrate those jobs using Glue workflows or step functions.

The benefit here is they are serverless and managed by aws while ecs you'll have to manage to start with and is also a overkill for this task.